# При установленном django-crispy-forms возникает ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: no module named crispy_forms

Tags: django, form, bootstrap4

При запуске python manage.py runserver возникает ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'`. Все делал по документации.
Вот мои installed_apps

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

А это pip freeze

```
asgiref==3.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
crispy-bootstrap4==2022.1
Django==4.1.7
django-bootstrap4==22.3
django-crispy-forms==2.0
Pillow==9.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.5
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
soupsieve==2.4
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.7
```

Прочитал документации попробовал через shell импортировать, написать название по другому, вместо crispy_forms, crispy_bootstrap, django_crispy_forms но все время возникает ModuleNotFoundError. Подскажите ошибку пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так. Сначала удалил crispy-forms

```
pip uninstall django-crispy-forms
```

А затем установил заново, но через python -m

```
python -m pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Кстати, решение применимо и к другим библиотекам. Применял данное решение и к psycopg2, когда django выводил ошибку `no module named psycopg2`.